# Nest returns zero results with MatchAll() Query and Size(100000)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have the following Nest query in C#:

```
var results = client.Search<Question>(s => s.From(0).Size(100000).Query(q=>q.MatchAll()));
```

When this is run I get zero results. When I adjust the Size() method to Size(10000) it works. I am basically trying to return all results in the index. What am I missing here? I have googled to find out if there is a max results settings on the Elastic server itself but have found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `index.max_result_window` settings (defaults to 10000) which [you can adjust](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html).

However, as described in the official documentation, if you want to retrieve all the documents, you're better off using [scroll search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) instead.

You can find an example of using scroll search with NEST [here](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/search/scroll.html)